# Rounded Texture Coordinate to Gradient Texture issue

Tags: shader-nodes

The triangles of this textures round, become circular, the closer to the middle. I would like them to be straight diagonal lines. How would I go about doing this purely with shader nodes?

[image]

Comment: You want rectangles that get wider towards the middle, all divided by straight diagonals?

Comment: Yes thanks Robin, that is correct.